# Create Element, then delete element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have an element be created then after a certain amount of time have be deleted.

My code works when I click my button once, it deletes the element after 2 seconds, but if I click the button multiple time the setTimeout function stops working.

```
function displayText(){
    var element = document.createElement("P");
    element.id = "text1";
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello'));
    document.getElementById('Div1').appendChild(element);
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("text1").style.display = "none";
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: You should probably define what's the desired behavior in case the button is clicked multiple times. For example, do you want to add more node, and each node should be deleted after 2 seconds from the click that generate it? Or if you clicked once then you shouldn't be able to add another element until the previous one is removed after 2 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having multiple IDs in a single document is **invalid HTML** - selecting the element with an `id` of `text1` in the `setTimeout` will only select the first element with that ID. Your newly created element doesn't need an ID at all - you can just reference the `element` variable in the closure, and set its style.

You also might find it easier to assign to the element's `textContent` than to use `createTextNode`:

```
function displayText(){
  var element = document.createElement("P");
  element.textContent = 'Hello';
  document.getElementById('Div1').appendChild(element);

  setTimeout(
    function(){
      element.style.display = "none";
    }, 2000);
}
```

Note that

```
element.style.display = "none";
```

doesn't actually delete the element - if you want to remove the element from the DOM, use

```
element.remove();
```